# How to avoid debian fall back to using lilo after update kernel

Tags: boot, debian, grub2, lilo

For some odd reason I have both lilo and grub installed on my dual boot debian/windows system. My default boot loader is grub, but after each kernel update my system starts using lilo, and I have to make a lot of work reinstalling grub in order to be able to "see" boths OSes. Is there any safe way to uninstall lilo. How it is guaranteed that grub will "see" new kernel after installing a new one?

Answer (score 0):

> How it is guaranteed that grub will "see" new kernel after installing a new one?

You can see the official documentation [FromLiloToGrub](https://wiki.debian.org/FromLiloToGrub)

Automatical grub update after installing a new Kernel

Add these lines to your `/etc/kernel-img.conf`:

```
postinst_hook = /usr/sbin/update-grub
postrm_hook = /usr/sbin/update-grub
do_bootloader = no
```